# Access Items in an object from Ajax Post and use it as datatable

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, vb.net

I have this JSON string data

```
{"data":[{"Action":"<button class=\"btn btn-primary btn-xs\" data-toggle=\"tooltip\" title=\"Edit Item\" id=\"editLineItm\" ><i class=\"fa fa-edit fa-fw\"></i></button> <button class=\"btn btn-danger btn-xs\" data-toggle=\"tooltip\" title=\"Remove Item\" id=\"deleteLineItm\"><i class=\"fa fa-times fa-fw\"></i></button>","LineId":0,"ServiceDesc":"Paragon","LineDescription":"3123","LineQty":"123.00","LineUnitPrice":"123.00","ContractId":"3","ServiceId":"2","LineSum":"15,129.00"},{"Action":"<button class=\"btn btn-primary btn-xs\" data-toggle=\"tooltip\" title=\"Edit Item\" id=\"editLineItm\" ><i class=\"fa fa-edit fa-fw\"></i></button> <button class=\"btn btn-danger btn-xs\" data-toggle=\"tooltip\" title=\"Remove Item\" id=\"deleteLineItm\"><i class=\"fa fa-times fa-fw\"></i></button>","LineId":1,"ServiceDesc":"IPVPN","LineDescription":"3","LineQty":"123.00","LineUnitPrice":"1.00","ContractId":"1","ServiceId":"4","LineSum":"123.00"}]}
```

from an AJAX post 
would like to access the items inside the json object to a web method in my webservice: Here's my code

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Function invExecInvLines(ByVal data As String)
    Dim t As DataTable = DirectCast(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data, (GetType(DataTable))), DataTable)
    For Each trow As DataRow In t.Rows
        MsgBox(trow("LineId"))
    Next
    Return ""
End Function
```

I am using JSON.net and deserializing seems to be not working, when I declare the function parameter as string, it throws this error "Message: Type System.String is not supported for deserialization of an array. ..." 
But when I use object it throws an error that cannot be used for datatable.

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Function invExecInvLines(ByVal data As object)
    Dim t As DataTable = DirectCast(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data, (GetType(DataTable))), DataTable)
    For Each trow As DataRow In t.Rows
        MsgBox(trow("LineId"))
    Next
    Return ""
End Function
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing the variable as object, I use generic list that suffice this. 
Adding an interface definition and generic collections.